# How to set count items per page by default in Laravel 5 paginate

Tags: laravel-5

In Laravel 5 if i use `Something::paginate()` i will get 15 items per page. Course i can do anytime`Something::paginate(20)`.

But how to override default count and use value from my .env?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can override the $perPage variable in your model by putting

```
   protected $perPage = 10;
```

inside your model that overrides the $perPage=15 original variable defined in Model.php

Comment: It is not perfect, that i should put this in each model. But good solution for my case. Thanks.

Comment: You can make a class that extends Model, put $perPage variable in it and then make all your models extend the new class, but it is not the best solution too.

Answer (score 11):

The question was asked ages ago, but if anyone needs a way to do it, you can just use a trait in your model. I had to get the per_page from the request to accept a 'all' and return all the records, with a max that can't go over.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Paginatable
{
    protected $perPageMax = 1000;

    /**
     * Get the number of models to return per page.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPerPage(): int
    {
        $perPage = request('per_page', $this->perPage);

        if ($perPage === 'all') {
            $perPage = $this->count();
        }

        return max(1, min($this->perPageMax, (int) $perPage));       
    }

    /**
     * @param int $perPageMax
     */
    public function setPerPageMax(int $perPageMax): void
    {
        $this->perPageMax = $perPageMax;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Please could you add usage to this answer? I've added this to my Model but the 'per_page' query parameter doesn't seem to be having an affect. Thanks.

Comment: How can i convert it to component and use it as module

Comment: Awesome. This should considered to be included as core feature.