# Is there a way in laravel 5 to manually decide on pagination numbers?

Tags: laravel, pagination

Currently working on a Laravel CRM for someone. I was wondering if there is a way to let the user decide how much results are displayed on a page? Something like this:[image]

Where the user decides how many records they wish to see on the page, so that they aren't limited to what is specified in the code. They wish to be able to print the records, so it would be great to have them be able to set the results to show all the records on 1 page when needed.

If you have an answer or a link to an article or video to help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible, but not out of the box. You'd need to find a package for that or code it yourself

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719397/how-to-set-count-items-per-page-by-default-in-laravel-5-paginate) possible solution?