# Why is my custom paginator not loading results as it should?

Tags: laravel, input, pagination

In my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611863/is-there-a-way-in-laravel-5-to-manually-decide-on-pagination-numbers?noredirect=1#comment108984288_61611863) I was asking how to let the user decide on pagination numbers. I thought I had figured it out, but now it appears I messed something up, as the pagination seems to work but as soon as you go to the next page, it's blank and the number of pages is set to 1.

importeren.blade.php page (this is where the data of the imported file(s) is shown). This also has the pagination links for Laravel, I feel the error could be within there but I am not 100% sure.
[image]

DataController index method that loads the amount of pages as specified by the user:
[image]

[Here](https://gyazo.com/05f974fd10a9c81e46c8cda11eea81cb) is a short clip displaying what happens once I enter the results for the amount of records to be displayed per page.

I do not know what I am missing, but if anyone could help out that'd be amazing.

Comment: Please use code snippets instead of images so other can copy and give you better examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append your parameter to each pagination link.
To do so you can use `{{$datas->appends(['paginate_number' => request('paginate_number')])->links()}}`

I will suggest to change method="POST" to method="GET" in the form.

Comment: That did the trick. Mind explaining me why you would put GET instead of POST? As you're essentially "posting" a number for use in a parameter.

Comment: 2 reasons mostly:
- when you first post the form the request('paginate_number')]) comes from form POST, but on next page it comes from query GET. This may be confusing.
- after first submit user will not have access to link with configuration and can't copy it and share (if he wants), also refreshing. That is why for pagination I prefer to pass all parameters in url

Answer (score 0):

First try as a static like this

```
$datas = Data::paginate(10);
```

If it works then you have to change `$request->input('paginate_number')`